# test method with jest and react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

i can´t get the answer, how cant reach the method inside a functional component iin react using jest and react-testing-library.

I tried with enzyme but i see all is changing to RTL.

```
import React from "react";

const simpleComponents = (props) => {

    const simpleMethod = () =>{ 
        // method logic
    };

    return <h1>test</h1>;
    };
}

export default simpleComponents;
```

Comment: What exactly are you testing? Can you post the full code within `simpleMethod`?

Comment: the problem is i dont know how can reach the method (simpleMethod ) inside the component (simpleMethod ) in the test, i need to wrap the method to test and get a posible result for "expect"                                                 
                                                                                                            
 describe("name", ()=>{it("name test2){ const wrapperFunctionsimpleMethod  = ???  })

Comment: Yes I understand. For class components, you can spy on the class properties/methods. However, for functional components, you can't. Therefore, the only thing you can do is to test for the behaviour, such as DOM changes, or props (for those, you can still spy on them). That's why I am asking for the full code so I know what to test for

Comment: ok, i think i understood, only i can reach the method on a class components, not in a functional component, i needed undertend the theory. thanks you!

Comment: I ran into the same problem today. If anyone must do it, you are going to have to create a separate suite and test the function separately, although RTL doesn't condone that. I was embarrassed to learn this from the team's solution architect.

Answer (score 7):

You should try to test only what your user would see in a real browser, and not your component internal logic. This is what react-testing-library promotes : writing tests that give confidence because they see/do what a real user would.

https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles

Following these guidelines, you should try to build a test which triggers user interactions on visible elements (rendered by your component), and which would involve the execution of simpleMethod.

This is the whole point of react-testing-library queries : getByText, getByPlaceholder, getByRole : things that a real user would see, hiding internal logic. But I guess you could have this approach with Enzyme (I never used Enzyme).

Writing tests with this approach leads to less tests, but stronger ones, which IMHO is a good thing. It is quite different from classical unit tests (say in a Java context for example) where you tests functions, inputs, outputs...

In fact your React component is a function, its inputs are user interactions, its output is a DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`simpleMethod` function is defined in the private scope of `simpleComponents` SFC. It's not exposed, so you can't get the function outside of `simpleComponents`.

But you can test it indirectly, for example:

```js
const simpleMethod = () =>{ 
  console.log('method logic');
};
```

Firstly, you need to use an event such as `click`, `submit` to trigger it. We add a `console.log` method, so we can spy on the `console.log` method, to check if `simpleMethod` function is called or not.