# RTL: test component with text rendered by inner function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a react component below that renders a message. In the component, a function grabs the current message based on the id and title. I'm trying to test the render of this component but RTL errors at the `{msg!.text}` line below. My understanding is that  --

```
"For class components, you can spy on the class properties/methods. However, for functional components, you can't."
```

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61307088/test-method-with-jest-and-react-testing-library))

Ok, fine. However, I keep going back to the RTL [principle](https://testing-library.com/docs/guiding-principles/) relating to the fact that this component is something a user ***would*** see in the application (although I admit
that on that ref page, #1 might apply to my use case here but i don't understand how).

Is there a way to define the msg.text here or test the component otherwise?

All I'm doing to get the error is this:

```
it('MailView', async () => {
  render(<MessageView title={"sent} id={0} />)
})
```

Component

```
 export function MessageView({ title, id }: MessageViewProps) {
  const bucket = title === "inbox ? received(user) : sent(user) 
  const msg = current(bucket, id)       // grab current mail message                                                                                    

  return(
    <Box>
      {msg!.text}     <------ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')
    </Box>
  );
}
```

dependencies

```
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.36",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
```

UPDATE: Referenced function

```
export function current(items: Message[], idx: number) {
  return items[idx];
}
```

Message.tsx

```
export interface Message {
  id: number
  date: string
  sender: string
  subject: string
  recipient: string
  text: string
}
```

Comment: What's the `current` function? please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @LinDu you are absolutely right, updated